# Is it possible to use software and hardware encryption together?

Tags: encryption, openssl, aes, hardware-acceleration

I'm trying to do Encryption using software and decryption by Hardware(AES-CTR mode algorithm).But facing some issue.software I'm using openssl logic. I tried  encryption by sw and Hw with same input but output is differnt :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encryption with hardware and software has different output.I guess that is ok. In fact that is how it should be. Normally due to random salting   you get different output.

When you do decryption,, decryption should work if both hard ware and software uses same salting mechanism